# Logical problem with list order

Tags: jquery

I think i kind off miss some logical insight. It seems so easy, but i just don't see it..

I have a list and want to see if there are list items before and/or after the clicked item. Here's the code

```
<script>
[..]
$("a").click(function(event){
 var parentEl = $(this).closest("ul");
 var currPosition = $(this).parent().prevAll().length + 1;
 var totalItems = $("#"+$(parentEl).attr("id")+" li").length;

 if(currPosition == totalItems){ alert("Previous and Next"); }
 if(currPosition <= totalItems){ alert("Next"); }
 if(currPosition >= totalItems){ alert("Previous"); } 
[..]
</script>

[..]

<ul id="listOne">
 <li><a>Text 1</a></li>
 <li><a>Text 2</a></li>
 <li><a>Text 3</a></li>
 <li><a>Text 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The code above almost works only one i click the last item, everything gets alerted..
I just want to know if there is a previous, next or both opions on the list-items that's clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
if(currPosition == totalItems){ 
  alert("Previous"); 
} else if(currPosition == 1){ 
  alert("Next"); 
} else {
  alert("Previous and Next");
}
```

Comment: Simple as hell! I knew it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make your life a little easier and use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to find something's current position.

```
$("a").click(function() {
  var li = $(this).closest("li");
  var items = li.parent().children();
  var currPosition = items.index(li);
  var totalItems = items.length();
  if (currPosition == 0) {
    // first
  } else if (currPosition == totalItems.length - 1) {
    // last
  } else {
    // middle
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can do tests like this:

```
if (li.is(":first-child")) {
  // first
} else if (li.is(":last-child")) {
  // last
} else {
  // in the middle
}
```

Comment: Could also do `li.index()` (assuming jQuery 1.4 or later).

Answer (score 0):

You can check using [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
  var pCount = $(this).closest('li').prevAll().length, //how many previous
      nCount = $(this).closest('li').nextAll().length; //how many after
  if(pCount > 0 && nCount > 0){ alert("Previous and Next"); }
  else if(nCount > 0){ alert("Next"); }
  else if(pCount > 0){ alert("Previous"); } 
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Cj9TE/), of course you can make this much shorter, but trying to illustrate where the counts are coming from, this method can tell you not only if there *are* previous/following elements like [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) would, but *how many*, if that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply a case of checking if their are items before or after the parent li.

```
$("a").click(function(){
      var itemsBefore = ($(this).parent().prev().length>0)
      var itemsAfter = ($(this).parent().next().length>0)
      if(itemsBefore && itemsAfter) alert("Previous and next");
      else if(itemsBefore) alert("Previous");
      else alert("Next");
  });
```

Working fiddle here --> http://jsfiddle.net/wmgvB/